# Emscripten claims I'm rendering without using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: c++, emscripten

I have been trying to run my c++ program online by using emscripten. However, it has been bombarding me with the error of :

> Looks like you are rendering without using requestAnimationFrame for the main loop. You should use 0 for the frame rate in emscripten_set_main_loop in order to use requestAnimationFrame, as that can greatly improve your frame rates!

But, the problem is that as far as I can tell, I am setting 0 fps in emscripten_set_main_loop_arg. So, I am unable to understand why I would be receiving this error when I am indeed rendering with requestAnimationFrame.

Here's the general break down of my main loop:

```
static void dispatchMain(void* fp)
{
    std::function<void()>* function = (std::function<void()>*)fp;
    (*function)();
}

void main()
{
    std::function<void()> mainLoop = [&]() {
        // Main loop calls here
    };

    emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(dispatchMain, &mainLoop, 0, 1);
}
```

Here's the general break down of the compilation command:

```
emcc -std=c++11 "Main.cpp" -s USE_GLFW=3 -s FULL_ES3=1 -DEMSCRIPTEN=1 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=167772160 -O3 -o out.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, for some reason using

```
glTimeinterval(0)
```

in the window class screwed up the framerate and caused the error.